# How to make Tomcat 8 work on port 80 and serve content on the internet

Tags: tomcat

I read a number of posts about this topic at SO and I am still unable to get Tomcat 8.0.32 to work.

Here is my environment: I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 connected on the internet. On it I installed Tomcat 8.0.32. I opened server.xml and changed port number from 8080 to 80 as follows:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"  />
 ...
</Connector>
```

I did not install anything on Tomcat and I am able to see content at

```
http://localhost:80
```

However, when I type in Chrome

```
http://example.com
```

I got error message: The webpage is not available.

If I shut down the Tomcat, start a IIS website (bind to port 80) on this server, and then type `http://example.com`, I am able to the web page served by IIS website.

This indicates that I need to do something about Tomcat, but I don't know what I need to do.

### Update

One more piece of information: Before the server, there is a load balancer (Kemp LoadMaster 3000). Not sure whether this thing needs configuration to let Tomcat serve the internet. But I cannot see how it is related somehow.

Comment: With Tomcat running on 8080, can you see it at http://example.com:8080?

Comment: IIS maybe holding on to the port, try the following see if it helps. Go to IIS -> Default Website and change the port for the default website and then restart IIS and then proceed to start your tomcat

Comment: When testing Tomcat, I disabled IIS website and application pool. Tomcat was able to start without any problem. It was able to serve content at localhost:80. Thanks for chiming in!

Comment: lancegoh, did what you said. No luck. Thanks.

Comment: @lancegoh If any other process was 'holding onto the port', Tomcat wouldn't start, and the `http://localhost:80' test wouldn't have worked.

Comment: Eric, I tried that. No luck. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working now. I need to add in-bound rule for port 80 in Firewall.

Don't know why the existing rule:

World Wide Web Services (HTTP Traffic-in)

only works for IIS. This rule opens port 80 too. Can someone explain why?

Comment: How did you do that? Could you explain the process?

Comment: I got help from a system guy. He added an in-bound rule for Firewall, which made the difference.